# Setting up makeup lights on this rotating jewelry cabinet

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, mirror

I want to buy this [jewelry cabinet](https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07L5G37PD) for my wife  (white one).

Now to ensure her face is sufficiently illuminated while getting prepared, I want to setup some lights along the wooden frame around the mirror. Could anyone suggest a better light setup for this?

Here are some challenges:

- The item is rotatable, hence risky to install something connected to the power outlet.
- Preferred to have at least 900 lumen or more in total. Please suggest if you have other opinion.
- When not in use, the lights must remain subtle and nearly unseeable state.

I'm considering [this one](https://www.amazon.ca/Luminoodle-Click-3-Pack-Lighting-Wireless/dp/B076B4QYPD) but it does not seem to have enough lumens. Other options are like either corded or separate lights will be extremely hard to build it nice and strong.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking for product recommendations. That's off topic here. If I've misunderstood, please revise to make that more clear.

Comment: It doesnt have to be an exact product but an idea of what type of lights might best fit the purpose would work as well.

Comment: I think you'd have to resort to a battery-powered solution, or maybe something rechargeable. There are lots of LED bars that would probably work well.

Comment: I got a roll of cheap but decent color LED strips for my wife's vanity. I used the sticky backing to affix to the mirror itself, along the edges; abutting against the wooden frame. They are hard to notice when turned off, but if you don't like the look, I would suggest leaving them very dimly lit, which keeps the eye from noticing the strip itself. She loves the bright even light. It came out great for about $5.

Answer (score 1):

**Make up mirror.**

[image: makeup mirror]

[source](https://www.wayfair.com/Symple-Stuff--Moe-Modern-and-Contemporary-Lighted-Magnifying-Makeup-Shaving-Mirror-X112361546-L41-K%7EW001250435.html?refid=GX434218169238-W001250435&device=c&ptid=905801902217&network=g&targetid=pla-905801902217&channel=GooglePLA&ireid=103590034&fdid=1817&gclid=CjwKCAiAnvj9BRA4EiwAuUMDfxt2_tAcUt-SxAvcLzfB1MmFkWytaAZqQFKopZdxzqgAh4-xkZ6ojhoCXSoQAvD_BwE)

Your cabinet has a full length mirror but not a makeup mirror and that is what she needs to do makeup.  A magnifying makeup mirror will also serve to reflect ambient light onto her face.  Install the makeup mirror and then make sure lighting for the room it is in is adequately bright (or can be made adequately bright) and the correct spectrum for applying makeup.

Comment: Really appreciate your suggestion. I am also thinking I probably need to change the plan completely.